# Python programming, writing your own functions or difficulty in finding built-in functions

Tags: python

In C#, there exists Structured Query Expression and with it, it's fun to play with collections and arrays. I am not sure if such a module exist in python. However SQE implements lambda, lambda expression also exist in python:

Let's imagine I need to get only distinct values from collection:

```
c# ex: 

List<int> arr = new List<int> {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
            List<int> arr2 = new List<int> { 2, 3, 4 };
            arr.AddRange(arr2);

            var qry = arr.Distinct();
            foreach (var x in qry)
                Console.WriteLine(x);
python ex:

arr = range(10) + [2,4,3]
def distinct(x):
    arr2 = []
    for y in x:
        if not y in arr2:
            arr2.append(y)
    return arr2

for x in distinct(arr):
    print x,
```

python solution maybe slow as if checks happen too much.

Comment: Please ask only one question per question. That makes it possible to compare all the answers. You can simply ask another question.

Answer (score 3):

Python has built-in support for [sets](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
arr = range(10) + [2,4,3]
for x in set(arr):
    print (x)
```

Note that sets are by nature without order; the order you get depends on the implementation of set, and is subject to change. In the rare case that you need to preserve the order, you should adapt your `distinct` method to look up in a set (with [runtime in](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_notation) `O(log n)`, or even `O(1)` amortized), instead of a list (`O(n)`), like this:

```
def distinct(iterable):
    seen = set()
    for el in iterable:
        if el not in seen:
            seen.add(el)
            yield el

for x in distinct(arr):
    print (x)
```

By the way, the implementation of `distinct` is an example of a [*generator*](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators). That means that the values are calculated just-in-time instead of being stored to a large list beforehand. Call [`list`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list) (as in `list(distinct(arr))`) if you want a conventional list (a resizeable array).

Answer (score 2):

To get unique values of a list in Python you can use set():

```
>>> lst = range(10) + [2,4,3]
>>> lst
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 4, 3]
>>> set(lst)
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to keep the original order, you should use a set or a dict for testing fastly if y has already been listed

```
arr = range(10) + [2,4,3]
def distinct(x):
    ToRet = []
    AuxDict = {}
    for y in x:
        if y not in AuxDict:
            AuxDict[y] = 0
            ToRet.append(y)
   return ToRet

for x in distinct(arr):
    print x,
```